# Why do the async keyword exists in JS?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

Why should I every time write the `async` keyword before each async function if that can be determined by presence of `await` keyword in the function code automatically?

```js
function foo() { // This function is sync because it has no await keyword.
    return new Promise(function(resolve)
    {
        setTimeout(function(){resolve("RESULT")},1000)
    })
}

function bar() { // This function is sync because it has no await keyword.
    return foo()
}

function baz() { // This function is obviously async because it contains an await keyword.
  console.log(await bar())
}

baz()
```

Moreover there is no need in `await` keyword also because it creates subtle problems:

```
async function foo() {
  throw new Error('foo');
}

async function bar() {
  try {
    return foo();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('caught with bar');
  }
}

bar(); // UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: foo
```

It could be replaced by a `nowait` keyword instead and resolving by default every function call if it is a promise:

```
async function foo() {
  throw new Error('foo');
}

async function bar() {
  try {
    return nowait foo(); // Now we clearly see what can cause the problem.
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('caught with bar');
  }
}

bar(); // UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: foo
```

And by combining these two approaches we get a clean code:

```
function foo() { // This function is async by default.
    return new Promise(function(resolve)
    {
        setTimeout(function(){resolve("RESULT")},1000)
    })
}

function bar() { // This function is deliberately sync because every function call in it is prepended by a nowait keyword.
    return nowait foo()
}

function baz() { // This function is also async because not EVERY function call is prepended by a nowait 
  console.log(nowait bar()) // Promise { <pending> }
  console.log(bar()) // "RESULT"
}

baz()
```

Also there could be both `sync/async` and `await/nowait` keywords used for everybody to be happy.
Did I missed something important in that reasoning?

Comment: Because javascript always target to keep things retrocompatible. Changings like you propose will break existing code

Comment: `console.log(nowait bar()) // Promise { <pending> }` why do you get this output? Isn't `bar` supposed to be synchronous?

Comment: This would require a complete static analysis of all code, including dependencies, in an application. It would require at least a minimal pseudo-run through the code in order to determine all possible return value types which, in a dynamic language like JS, is problematic at best, particularly since objects themselves can be modified at runtime. This is a solution in search of a problem, solving for the low percentage of functions that are async.

Comment: Unrelated but it seemed the syntax highlighter was not happy with having `function foo()` then a comment on the line, then the opening curly bracket on the next line. No idea why. Seems like a bug.

Comment: VLAZ, there is a bit confusion in terminology because `async` keyword is used in JS to describe a function that is meant to be synchronous right now. So I use `sync` and `async` in JS interpretation.

Comment: @user619271 no, `async` is most definitely used to describe a function as asynchronous. Not the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to answer this question from a dev perspective, not from technical perspective.

One thing you clearly missed is history.

First of all, the Web was much, much different when JS was firstly developed. So you might not like some solutions, but those decisions were made a long time ago.

You can't switch from "non-blocking" to "blocking" behaviour without breaking 90% of the web. Can you imagine the outrage such decision would cause among the devs? Moreover, JS runs on users browsers and we don't have control over users updating them. Checking for a user's browser version before sending JS script is not an option.

Now, every single function where you use "await" needs to return a Promise, otherwise it wouldn't make any sense.

This is why "async" keyword was introduced - you look at the function and you know at first glance that it returns a Promise, because every async function returns a Promise. Otherwise, you would have to analyse the whole function's code and check whether it contains any "await" operations.

Comment: As far as I know async functions can return not only promises that's why I introduced a `bar` function in my example.

Comment: Now I tested it and can actually see that I was wrong!

Comment: This is something many developers forget. async function fn(){ return "abc"; } returns a Promise, automatically resolved with value "abc".